# SQL developer Import data wizard comes up blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, import, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have a file that has over 100 entries in it as an excel worksheet.  I want to put those over into a sql.  So I fire up my sql developer and try and import the data but it doesn't show up.

[image: No data to preview]

The next and finish buttons don't do anything. (the blue underline words aren't links to anything either fyi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried converting the original file to text (csv) then importing? That has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the only way to get rid of it was to rename the preferences folder (as described here: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/08/how-to-reset-your-sql-developer-preferencessettings/) and start the program with factory defaults.

Answer (score 0):

One more reason is that the CSV or excel file is of 0 kb size or empty.